# Как отработать event в клонированном элементе после clone() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ для того, чтобы сделать стилизованные селекты.

```
.repeat
  select.selectpicker.color.col-xs-3 data-width="fit" action=text1
    option data-content="<div class='colorpreview' style='background-color:red' ></div>" 1
    option data-content="<div class='colorpreview' style='background-color:blue'></div>" 2
```

Отрабатываю данные из селектов через

```
$('.color').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
  ...
  action = $(this).attr('action');
  console.log(action);
});
```

Далее написал копирование последнего селекта:

```
$('.addText').click(function() {
  var count = $('.color').length;
  var next = count + 1;
  $('.color[action=text'+ count +']').clone(true).attr('action', 'text'+ next).appendTo('.repeat');
});
```

В итоге элемент копируется, но при изменении в копированном элементе значении, отрабатывается event прородителя. Это обнаружно через вывод атрибута action в консоль (action c каждым новым элементом изменяется textN, где N=N+1)

Как скопированные элементы сделать независимыми и самодостаточными?

Comment: сделай пример который можно запустить, тут в сниппете, либо на каком нибудь из сервисов типа jsfiddle. Код выглядит рабочим

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=lGO5bpAzHb

Comment: вооот :-) теперь все понятно. Если посмотришь разметку получающуюся - тоже увидишь что не так

Comment: Да, увидел, спасибо. Но проблема не исчезла, если сделать div обертку у selecta для копировании... хоть и разметка больше не содержит ошибочных action

Comment: UPD: https://jsfiddle.net/qvhgk33x/1/#&togetherjs=lGO5bpAzHb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логика в обработчике была не совсем верна.

Данный плагин скрывает основной селект оборачивая его в свою разметку и перенося его атрибуты в див. Получалось. что сразу после загрузки класс *color* был у селекта и его контейнера, при этом они оба являются последними детьми на своих уровнях, поэтому выбирались оба.

Вместо этого стоит брать последний селект, например по классу selectpicker, и инициализировать плагин непосредственно на нем.

При этом, так как теперь селект копируется без событий, обработчик событий стоит делегировать с помощью метода [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

В итоге все может выглядеть так:

```js
$('.addText').click(function() {
  var count = $('.selectpicker').length;
  var next = count + 1;
  var picker = $('.selectpicker').eq(-1).clone().attr('action', 'text' + next).appendTo('.repeat');
  picker.selectpicker(picker.data());
});

$('.repeat').on('changed.bs.select', '.selectpicker', function(e) {
  action = $(this).attr('action');
  console.log(action);
});
```

```css
select {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.colorpreview {
  background: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<div class=repeat>
  <select class="selectpicker color col-xs-3" data-width="fit" action=text1>
    <option data-content="<div class='colorpreview' style='background-color:red' ></div>">1</option>
    <option data-content="<div class='colorpreview' style='background-color:blue'></div>">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button class=addText>Копировать последний select</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает!